# Type for sending array of objects to child component so index [1] doesn't have to be specified

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The API returns an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "odd": 7,
        "even": 42
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "odd": 1,
        "even": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "odd": 31,
        "even": 6
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "odd": 17,
        "even": 62
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "odd": 13,
        "even": 4
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "odd": 21,
        "even": 12
    }
]
```

I want to pass this to a child component that iterates through the area of objects and prints out `id`, `odd`, and `even`.

What I can get working is doing the following:

```
// ParentComponent.tsx
...
<ChildItems {...response} />
...
```

```
// ChildComponent.tsx

type ReponseProps = {
  id: number;
  odd: number;
  even: number;
}[];


const ChildItems = (props: ResponseProps): JSX.Element => {
  console.log(props);
  return <></>;
};
```

Which creates an object that looks like:

```
{
  "0": {
      "id": 1,
      "odd": 7,
      "even": 42
  },
  "1": {
      "id": 2,
      "odd": 1,
      "even": 2
  },
  "2": {
      "id": 3,
      "odd": 31,
      "even": 6
  },
  "3": {
      "id": 4,
      "odd": 17,
      "even": 62
  },
  "4": {
      "id": 5,
      "odd": 13,
      "even": 4
  },
  "5": {
      "id": 6,
      "odd": 21,
      "even": 12
  }
}
```

Then I have to do something like the following to access each element:

```
const ChildItems = (props: SolutionProps): JSX.Element => (
  <>
  {
    Object.entries(props).map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <p key={item[1].id}>{item[1].even} - {item[1].odd}</p>
      )
    })
  }
  </>
);
```

What strikes me as weird is having to do `item[1]`: messy and seems like it shouldn't be necessary.

So that is my question: **How should I build the passing of props to a child component, and `type` in the child component, to get around having to specify the index?**

I've tried doing the following in the parent component:

```
// ParentComponent.tsx
...
<ChildComponent res={response} />
...

// ChildComponent.tsx
const ChildItems = (res: SolutionProps): JSX.Element => 
  ...
```

But always get a: `Property 'res' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & SolutionProps'.`

Probably a way to this and I'm just screwing it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Props should be a *plain object*, not an array, where each property of the props argument is treated similarly to an argument in a normal function. Right now, you're typing the props as an array, and you're also not passing an array, but an object as props when you do

```
<ChildItems {...response} />
```

(which spreads each enumerable own property of the response into the props object - resulting in your `{ 0: ... 1: ... }` structure that's hard to work with)

Change to something like:

```
<ChildItems {...{ response }} />
// or
<ChildItems response={response} />
```

and

```
const ChildItems = ({ response }: { response: ResponseProps }) => {
```